# Facebook page plugin, on local host?

Tags: html, facebook, plugins

I have this html code:[image]

and this is how it looks like:

[image]

But, I want it to look like this:

[image]

Can it be done on local host? Or I am mistaking somewhere?

Comment: Also, you probably need an actual local server.  `file://` has a variety of issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sr_RS/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

That is a protocol-relative URL, and as such this can not work when you access your HTML document just via `file://`.

Either install a local web server for testing purposes, so that you can access your pages via `http://` in the browser; or modify the code above to include the protocol,

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/sr_RS/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

(But then don’t forget to undo that again, before you upload your site to an actual webserver.)

Answer (score 0):

You not doing anything wrong, just facebook API's or plugins not working offline.
You must have hosting to put code on it and then try to test it will work for sure.

Comment: @Никола Пејић did u check my answer ?